Is possible to get windows default dialog font (MS Shell Dlg) and change its attributes, e.g. bold?
I want to make header (CHeaderCtrl) of CListCtrl bold. I dont want to develop my own font, because I want to respect system default font, which is on each computer different. I want  only make default font bold. Is it possible? Below code throw error:
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mfc140ud.dll
File: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\wingdi.cpp
Line: 1113

in line: m_headerFont.CreateFontIndirect(&lf); - see picture below. 
In moment of breakpoint is value of lf:
   lfHeight: -12
   lfWidth: 0
   lfEscapement: 0
   lfOrientation: 0
   lfWeight: 700
   lfItalic: 0 '\0'
   lfUnderline: 0 '\0'
   lfStrikeOut: 0 '\0'
   lfCharSet: 1 '\x1'
   lfOutPrecision: 0 '\0'
   lfClipPrecision: 0 '\0'
   lfQuality: 0 '\0'
   lfPitchAndFamily: 0 '\0'
   lfFaceName: 0x00000004b38fc8cc L"Segoe UI"

Code example:
class CMFCtestDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    CFont m_headerFont;
    //....
    //...
    BOOL OnInitDialog();
}

BOOL CMFCtestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    //.......
    //.......
    CFont *pDefaultFont = pHeaderCtrl->GetFont();
    LOGFONT lf{0};
    if(pDefaultFont != nullptr && pDefaultFont->GetLogFont(&lf))
    {
        // If the font is MS Shell Dlg, use SystemParametersInfo to get the system font
        if(_tcscmp(lf.lfFaceName, _T("MS Shell Dlg")) == 0)
        {
            if(SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETICONTITLELOGFONT, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf, 0))
            {
                lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
                m_headerFont.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
                pHeaderCtrl->SetFont(&m_headerFont);
            }
        }
    }
}


Please post assertion failure as text in yet another code block, you can take the text in the Debug output or copy it from the dialog using a keyboard shortcut.

The assertion fails because the GDI object handle passed to the CGdiObject::Attach() function (CFont inherits from CGdiObject) is NULL (check line 1113 in wingdi.cpp). And it is NULL because the call of Win32 CreateFontIndirect() failed previously.

Thanks, but why is NULL? I have added to my question more detailed information about lf. Could it be because if font lf is system font?

@MichalHadraba This is just a repeat of your previous question, which was closed for lack of detail. If you had more info to add, you should have just edited that question so it could be re-opened. Too late now, but please keep it in mind for future questions.

I am sorry. I did not know, that it could be re-open.

Note: "MS Shell Dlg" is (effectively) just an alias for "Microsoft Sans Serif". There is only a regular weight; if you set lfWeight to 700, you will get synthetically-bolded text. "MS Shell Dlg" / Microsoft Sans Serif has not been the primary UI font in Windows for over 20 years. If you want a consistent look with the rest of the Windows shell, you should use Segoe UI.

But Visual Studio 2020 sets the default font, if I use the dialog designer, MS Shell dlg (as you write Sans Serif).

Well, my comment above was wrong, I thought it was failing because it couldn't create the font with the parameters you had passed. But the reason is that the m_headerFont object already contains a valid font handle at that point. You are reusing the object, but CFont::CreateFontIndirect() calls CGdiObject::Attach(), which "asserts" that the object is "empty" (m_hObject==NULL). Therefore you must use another CFont object or instead clear m_headerFont before the CreateFontIndirect() call:
    .
    .
    DeleteObject(m_headerFont.Detach()); // detach and delete the old HFONT
    m_headerFont.CreateFontIndirectW(&lf);
    .
    .


Great!!! Thanks.
